# Fine tuning a pretrained model gives worse results

Tags: machine-learning, keras, finetuning

I have a pretrained model for multi-class activity classification. I also have a dataset D which is similar to the dataset used to train the pretrained model.

When I run data from D through the pretrained model, the classification accuracy is high (97% accuracy, 97% F1 score).

However, when I fine tune the pretrained model with D and test the fine-tuned model with a held out set from D, the performance drops considerably (~40% F1 score). Additionally, one of the classes is not detected at all.

The classes are imbalanced but I get similar results when I retrain after balancing the dataset D.

Has anyone faced similar issues?